# Use regular expression to search in arabic text in C#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, search, arabic

I want to create search module in Arabic text by regular expression and C#. Can any one help me? I don't have any idea.
In my search module, when user inert "من" without Alphabet (ُ َ ِ ), module return مُن مِن مَن and others. how to create this module?
thanks.

Comment: A search module in what kind of application, searching what kind of data? What have you tried, and why doesn't it work? Are you just trying to search Arabic strings for a user-specified pattern?

Answer (score 8):

Regular expression to identify arabic words is

**[ء-ي]+**

You can validate this expression [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) here, it might not be the perfect answer but will give you a start at least[image: output]

here is a small code in C#

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool results = checkArabicWords("مرحبا كيف حالك");
            Console.WriteLine(results);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
       static bool checkArabicWords(string arabicText)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[ء-ي]+");
            return regex.IsMatch(arabicText);

        }
  }
```

Out of the above code is 
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Can arabic words contain any punctuation (analogous to hyphens or apostrophes) that might need to be included in the set of characters?

Comment: It wasn't meant a a rhetorical question; I don't know the first thing about Arabic writing. I just thought it was worth considering, especially since it's the kind of thing that might slip past simple test data and cause problems in production.

Comment: Oh, and you should consider using `*` instead of `+` so you can capture single characters.

Comment: @octern but i think *  will only capture the last character not individual character in arabic word

Comment: Doesn't `*` just mean "match the preceding character zero or more times?"

Comment: @MMK when i use [ء-ي]+ all word selected. and when use "ع\u064E[ء-ي]" for detect "عَ" such "عَبدالله" not select the words. \u0650 means fatha "َ-" iin this link: [link](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/morph/buckwalter.html)

Comment: @1mohammadi.ir you need to write whole regular expression in Unicode format.